# From Rest to Final Velocity (Free -Falling Physics Problem)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, free-fall

I am notorious for over thinking and I am having a problem with this question:

> On another planet, a marble is released from rest at the top of a high cliff. It falls 4.00 m in the first 1 s of its motion. Through what additional distance does it fall in the next 1 s? (a) 4.00 m (b) 8.00 m (c) 12.0 m (d) 16.0 m (e) 20.0 m

The answer is (c) 12.0 m. I can set up the equations and do the math, but it is the conceptional part of the problem that is making me feel lost.

My question is, if the acceleration is 8.0 m/s^2, then why didn't it fall 8.00 m in the first second of its motion (since the initial velocity was 0m/s at t = 0 s)?
I know that at one second the marble fell 4 m which would make the velocity 4 m/s, and with the acceleration equaling  8 m/s^2 the velocity at 2 s would be 12 m/s (falling an additional 12 m). So, again, why did the velocity start increasing 8.0 m/s^2 only after the first second?

I'd appreciate any help! I'm quite puzzled :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if the acceleration is 8.0 m/s^2, then why didn't it fall 8.00 m in the first second of its motion (since the initial velocity was 0m/s at t = 0 s)?

Because the distance it moves in a second depends on the average speed it has during that period, not the maximum speed.

> why did the velocity start increasing 8.0 m/s^2 only after the first second?

It started increasing immediately.  But it takes a (full) second to reach 8m/s.

It began the first second of falling with a speed of 0 and ended the first second of falling with a speed of 8m/s.

The average speed during the first second was therefore only 4m/s.

Answer (score -1):

As the marble gains the velocity of 8m/s only after 1sec, it can't cover distance of 8m in first second.